# Retrieving foreign key value using substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, inner-join, sql-server-2014

I have the below output table from a table called DrugEvents in which the Age column has age value and its unit. The query I used to get the below table is given below.

[image]

The unit values are available in another table called AgeUnit. This table has a primary key called AgeUnitID and another column called AgeUnitNAme. I need to insert values to a table called Patient retrieving the Age, Sex, Weight, Country and FKAgeUnitID. Currently I have the below query.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(d.Age, 1, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', d.Age)
    WHEN 0
        THEN LEN(d.Age)
    ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', d.Age) - 1
    END) AS Age,
    Sex,
    SUBSTRING(d.[Weight], 1, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', d.[Weight])
    WHEN 0
        THEN LEN(d.[Weight])
    ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', d.[Weight]) - 1
    END) AS [Weight],
    Country,
    d.Age
FROM DrugEvents d
```

In the above query I am selecting d.Age instead of the FKAgeUnitID. How can I select the FKAgeUnitID that matches the Age unit value in Age column? That is, for 1st record it should find "YR" in "61 YR" and get its AgeUnitID and select that in the above query where I currently have d.Age. Please advice.

Comment: You have 2 `Age` columns in one table - thats not possible.

Comment: That output is a select query I ran. The second age column should be the FKAgeUnitID. It shows age since I've given d.age in the above query

Comment: Your question literally starts `I have the below table called DrugEvents...`

Comment: All the values in the Age column are 'YR'. Are there other units?

Comment: Yes they are YR, HR and MIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SUBSTRING() in the ON criteria in the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT au.AgeUnitID,
       d.Age
    --,other columns
FROM DrugEvents d
JOIN AgeUnit au
ON au.AgeUnit = SUBSTRING(d.Age, CHARINDEX(' ', d.Age), LEN(d.Age))
```

in the same way as you have in your SELECT list. Does that do what you want?

This assumes the age and unit are always both present and space-delimited, but if that's not the case then, again, you can use the same logic as you're already using in the SELECT list.